# Master Page data didn't show in other pages in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, header

I'm new in asp.net, I am currently in the basic of master.pages.

I am testing how to put an image header to my master page.

Here's my master.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="master.master.cs" Inherits="master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">

    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="headerImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cross-header.gif" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/master.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

When I run this, The imageHeader that I put in the master.master, didn't show up.

Any assistance from you guys will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to see the image in all your pages, move out image from ContentPlaceHolder in your MasterPage

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="headerImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cross-header.gif" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

TO :

```
    <asp:Image ID="headerImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cross-header.gif" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: I'm glad you helped. We're All Here to Learn, never stop asking;)